# How to ask if location is enabled before map initializes?

Tags: android, location

How to ask if location is enabled before map initializes ?
If I try to ask for permission on MapsActivity all it does is quit the application because it is not enabled.
I have tried adding it to the activity that directs the users to the Map. But it still just closes the activity unless the location is enabled.

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
        setUpMap();

    }
    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    retrieveAndAddCities();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrive cities", e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Marker mClosestMarker;
    float mindist;

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            double lat = jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0);
            double lon = jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1);
            final String address = jsonObj.getString("address");
            Marker currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                    .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population"))).draggable(true)
                    .position(new LatLng(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0), jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Call Local Distributor " + marker.getTitle())
                            .setMessage("Would you like to dial now ? ")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + marker.getSnippet()));
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                }
                            })
                            .create()
                            .show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            float[] distance = new float[1];
            Location.distanceBetween(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), lat, lon, distance);
            if (i == 0) {
                mindist = distance[0];
            } else if (mindist > distance[0]) {
                mindist = distance[0];
                mClosestMarker = currentMarker;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        mClosestMarker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(100);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
    }

}
```

I tired using this snippet in OnCreate, but still if location is disabled the application fails to start.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        // Build the alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: You question is not very clear. What is exact your problem?

Comment: When my application is started, if the location services is disabled I want it to ask them to enable it. If it is enabled just run the application as it is. But i've tried literally everything and cannot get it to ask to enable the location services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is my code snippet that i use for my application it works fine check it it will work for you as well

```
int off = 0;

    try {
        off = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (off == 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("GPS is not enbled.");
        builder.setMessage("To Get Your Current Location You have To Enable Gps \n Are Sure Want to go to seeting to Enable GPS?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing but close the dialog
                Intent onGPS = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(onGPS);

                // Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, c_lat +","+c_long, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```